# How to refer to a partial view of another controller in a view?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, controller, partial-views

The title pretty much states my question.

I have a view (say, `Action1`) in a controller (`Foo`) and another view (`Action2`) in another controller (`Bar`). In `Action1` view, I want to use `Html.Partial` or `Html.RenderPartial` to call `Action2`'s view.

I am aware of that I can use `Html.RenderAction` in `Action1`, but that will (I think) create the `Bar` controller and go through the whole controller/action resolution cycle, and I don't want that, as this may be less efficient.

So, my goal is that I want to reuse the `Action2`'s veiw. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider moving the partial to the **Views\Shared** folder.

Then you can render it from anywhere:

E.g:

**Razor:**

```
@Html.Partial("SharedView")
```

**ASPX:**

```
<%: Html.Partial("SharedView") %>
```

If you don't want to do that, then pull as much markup from the main partial as you can into a **custom display template**, then re-use that across the two Views.

And yes, your right about `@Html.Action` going through the request pipeline, and `@Html.Partial` not.